# Error when importing sklearn in python - ImportError

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, package-managers

I get an error when importing sklearn in python.

I am using MacBook.

```py
>>> import sklearn
```

Error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
>     import sklearn   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py",
> line 81, in <module>
>     from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401 ImportError: cannot import name '__check_build' from 'sklearn'
> (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py)
```

Comment: How did you install `sklearn` on your machine?

Comment: using pip install sklearn in terminal

Comment: Why not install Anaconda which includes that?

Comment: @NeePew it is not pip install sklearn but `pip install scikit-learn`

Answer (score 1):

According to [the pypi page for sklearn](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/), you should be using `pip install scikit-learn` instead of `pip install sklearn`

Answer (score 0):

Your `requirements.txt` file needs the line

```
scikit-learn==0.22.1
```

or, if you're not storing requirements for the project, then

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

on the command line.